# Adding a view (image view) in between two UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a `UITableView` programatically. And i am loading it with data. I want to insert an advertisement Banner (clickable button which is equal to cell's height and width) into this `table view` after every 4 rows. Is it possible to insert that ? or should i add something to array which i am loading the table view with ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add it as a header/footer of 4th or 5th cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The table view owns its whole area, and renders cells based on it's internal logic.

You could divide your table view into sections and add a custom cell as a section header or footer, or you could make your cellForRowAtIndexPath serve up a custom type of cell for every 4th row that ONLY contains your full-sized button. That should accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 2):

As Duncan mentioned you could use cellForRowAtIndexPath and place a custom cell type for every 4th row. You can set two types of custom cells in your tableview by setting the `identifier` property. Ex. For every 4th row use the "ad" identifier cell.