# Is it possible to add a view between two UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Similar question: [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943060/adding-a-view-image-view-in-between-two-uitableviewcells)

However, that question was asked 3 years ago. So there might be a possibility that it's possible now. Here's the UI I'm making. The **active view** is in between the two cells. I did similar thing to this in my past project, however, that similar view is not in between the two cells.

[image]

What I have done so far is to make the bottom constraint of this **active view** to be something like **-15** to make it center at the bottom of the cell. But when the app is run, of course you will not see the half of the **active view**.

Comment: Its not really similar, the other question is asking how to put another kind of cell in every 4th row, yours is adding a view between 2 cell. Also I dont think its no easy way to do what you needed, maybe try just put the view there and use `clipToBounds = false` on the cell and see if it still visible between

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of how you're not seeing "half of the active view"? Perhaps you have `clipsToBounds` set to `true` for the parent view? You can either change it programmatically or change it in the "Attributes inspector" and deselect "Clips to Bounds".

Comment: Hey guys, I edited my question. I think I have solved this. But agian, the clip to bounds didn't solve it. Should I delete this question?

Comment: You can post an answer yourself if you were able to resolve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Adeel suggested to post my edit as the answer.

Thanks for the comments. setting to true clipToBounds of that `active view` didn't solve it. I'm setting that property in my storyboard.

Here's the screenshot of my testings. I'm doing the tests in my other project.

I managed to solve this by rather adding a view to the bottom of the imageView, rather than putting them in the next TableViewCell.

*This is no brainer, why didn't you think about this solution before posting a question?*

-- Someone might ask in the future. I didn't think about this, because I'm using a third-party library for stretchable header called [GSKStretchyHeaderView](https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView).

[image]

Comment: you have some code snippets? (from your description i can not imagine how you have done it.)

Comment: It doesn't need a code, @muescha. I'm doing the whole UI using the IB / storyboard.

Comment: Then a screenshot of IB? Thx